# R: Parsing group of html files with loop

Tags: html, xml, r, rcurl

The following code works for individual .html files:

```
doc <- htmlParse("New folder/1-4.html")
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//td", xmlValue)
plain.text <- gsub("\n", "", plain.text)
gregexpr("firstThing", plain.text)
firstThing <- substring(plain.text[9], 41, 50)
gregexpr(secondThing, plain.text)
secondThing <- substring(plain.text[7], 1, 550)
```

But the following loop does not and gives me the error:

XML content does not seem to be XML

```
file.names <-  dir(path = "New folder")

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
doc <- htmlParse(file.names[i])
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//td", xmlValue)
gsub("\n", "", plain.text)
firstThing[i] <- substring(plain.text[9], 41, 50)
secondThing[i] <- substring(plain.text[7], 1, 550)
  }
```

I'm simply trying to extract the information (as I've been able to do in the first batch of code), and create a vector of information.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yep, and thanks for pointing that out, but it still doesn't solve the error problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First, your paths were wrong. To fix this, use:

```
filenames = dir(path = "New folder", full.names = TRUE)
```

Secondly, a better way than filling two variables inside a `for` loop is to generate structured data in a list function:

```
result = lapply(filenames, function (filename) {
    doc = htmlParse(filename)
    plain_text = xpathSApply(doc, "//td", xmlValue)
    c(first = substring(plain_text[9], 41, 50),
      second = substring(plain_text[7], 1, 550))
})
```

Now `result` is a list of elements, where each element is a vector with names `first` and `second`.

A few other remarks:

- Be wary of dots in variable names — S3 uses dots in names to determine the class of a generic method. Using dots for anything else in variable names causes confusion and should be avoided.
- The `gsub` statement in your loop has no effect.

Comment: Actually, this is returning the same information to each cell -- so it doesn't appear to be looping through the files. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2880936 A simple typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you Konrad.